# One of the pom file was lost , why maven install still suceess?

Tags: java, maven

Today I found that after I delete a pom file like a.pom and leave an a.jar file  exist, Mvn install can still success. but the result jar lost some dependency descriped in a.pom . So I wonder what's the releastionship between a.jar and a.pom file? Is every maven module after installing has an a.jar and a.pom file ?

also I found that there already an a.pom file inside a.jar ,why there still an a.pom file outside a.jar. what's the difference?

Cause I am new to maven , maybe there is something basic knowledge in maven I dont know.

thanks for answering.

Comment: You probably got a warning in your build about missing POM files.

Comment: Suggest reading https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM